# Is it possible to find an estimate of $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{\varphi(k\cdot p_k)}$?

Tags: analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, sequences-and-series, arithmetic-functions

Is it possible to find an estimate of the summation
$$s(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{\varphi(k\cdot p_k)}$$
where $\varphi(n)$ is the totient function and $p_k$ the k-th prime?

The corresponding series seems to converge to the value
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}s(n)=1.86491\ldots$$
but I don't see a simple way to prove it.

Many thanks.

Comment: $\frac{1}{\varphi(kp_k)}=\frac{1}{(p_k-1)\varphi(k)}$. Now use any reasonable lower bound on $\varphi(k)$, like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/301837/127263)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand\vpi\varphi$[It is known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Growth_rate) that
$$\vpi(n)\ge\frac n{c\ln\ln(n+10)}=:\psi(n)$$
for some real $c>0$ and all natural $n$. Also, $\psi$ is increasing on the interval $[N,\infty)$ for some natural $N$.
Therefore and because $p_k\ge k$ for all $k$,
$$\sum_{k\ge N}\frac1{\vpi(kp_k)}\le\sum_{k\ge N}\frac1{\psi(kp_k)}
\le\sum_{k\ge N}\frac1{\psi(k^2)}<\infty.$$